# A simple wordpress gallery that you can attach to a page?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, gallery

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good simple image gallery plugin for Wordpress, where you can attach a gallery to a Page and get those images on said Page.

All of the popular solutions for galleries in Wordpress seem to to be self-contained solutions with several unneeded bells and/or whistles.

So has any one used a good simple plugin where a page can just have some images.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know such plugins, but I can suggest one solution for that.

```
   <?php
   if(is_page) {
      global $post;
      $images = get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $post->ID );

      foreach($images  as $image ) {
         echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID);
      }
   }
   ?>
```

Above code return all attached images (from gallery) of current page.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, or do you just want the `[gallery]` [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode)? (Add `[gallery]` to the text of your post in the place you want the related images displayed...)